# SVGTSpanElement.createShadowRoot doesn't work

Tags: html, dom, svg, shadow-dom, custom-element

Can you please help me with following code?
In Webkit family, I see the shadow element (in developer tools), but doesn't appear at all on screen.
In Firefox, it crashes!
I suspect namespaces, because it works great for HTML elements like `HTMLDivElement`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
<script>
var proto = Object.create(SVGTSpanElement.prototype);
proto.attachedCallback = function() {
    if (!this.shadowRoot) this.createShadowRoot();
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(document.createTextNode('superb!!!!!'));
}
var XLang = document.registerElement('lang-tspan', { prototype: proto, extends: 'tspan' });
</script>
<svg width="300" height="100"><text x="10" y="20">This is <tspan is="lang-tspan">my substitution</tspan></text></svg>
</html>
```

Comment: If Firefox crashes, raise a bugzilla bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core

Comment: I'm not sure that Shadow DOM works with SVG elements. Never found any examples.

Comment: It is true, that, term "svg" never happen in ShadowDOM specs...